# Empaquetado en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

¿Cómo puedo empaquetar los octetos?

```
def solicitud_WRQ_Oct(filename, sock, octects):
     modo ='octeto'
     WRQ = struct.pack('!H' + str(len(filename)) + 'sB' + b"6sx" + 'sB', 2, bytes(filename, 'octeto'), 0, bytes(modo, 'octeto'), 0)
```

Sé que debería ir entre 'sB' y la coma ',', pero no sabría cómo ponerlo, ni cómo ponerlo después del último 0.

Comment: indica por favor cuál es tu salida actual y cuál quieres que sea, para que se entienda mejor el problema

Comment: @fedorqui ahora mismo no me es posible ejecutarlo. Pero tal vez con esto lo entiendas mejor. :                                                                               
         + ------- + --- ~~ --- + --- + --- ~~ --- + --- + --- ~~ --- + --- + - - ~~ --- + -
       |  opc | nombre de archivo |  0 |  modo |  0 |  blksize |  0 |  #octets |  0 |
       + ------- + --- ~~ --- + --- + --- ~~ --- + --- + --- ~~ --- + --- + - - ~~ --- + ---   Me gustaría saber como puedo poner blksize y #octets de la manera de ordenamiento y de valor : struct.pack(ordenamiento, valor)

Comment: dale a [edit] y añade esta info a la pregunta, que si no en comentarios se ve fatal :)

Comment: Por curiosidad ¿eso es la implementación de una petición de escritura a un server por protocolo TFTP? ¿Qué es exactamente lo que recibe mediante el argumento octects?

Answer (score 0):

Según las especificaciones definidas en  [RFC 2348](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2348) el tamaño de los bloques debe ser un valor entre 8 y 65464 y se especifican en ASCII. Por lo tanto debes hacer algo así, suponiendo que usas Python 3.x, `filename` es de tipo `str` (UTF-8) y `octects` un entero en el rango `8 <= octects <= 65464`:

```
import struct



def solicitud_WRQ_Oct(filename, sock, octects):
    ascii_filename = filename.encode('utf-8')
    blocksize = str(octects).encode("utf-8")

    formatt = f'!H{len(ascii_filename)}sB6sB7sB{len(blocksize)}sB'
    wrq = struct.pack(formatt,
                      2,
                      ascii_filename,
                      0,
                      b'octect',
                      0,
                      b'blksize',
                      0,
                      blocksize,
                      0
                      )
    print(wrq)
```

> ```
> >>> solicitud_WRQ_Oct("foobar.txt", None, 1428)    
> b'\x00\x02foobar.txt\x00octect\x00blksize\x001428\x00'
> ```